# Reading a file one char at a time

Tags: c, readfile

I have two `.c` files: one contains the main and the other contains all of my functions.

In my main I have a part where I want to read a char at a time the loop looks like this:

```
while(ch = ReadFile(fp)) != EOF)
{
    // Code
}
```

where `ch` is an integer (`int ch;`) and `fp` is a file pointer (`FILE* fp;`).

And (different `.c` file ---):

```
int ReadFile(FILE* fp)
{
    // Some code
    return n; // The next char
}
```

Does anyone know how I can read one char at a time from the main this way, using this method?

Comment: I'd avoid using the name `ReadFile` if you want your code to be portable, since Windows defines [a function of the same name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and function overloading is not allowed in C.

Comment: If you're not allowed to use a function such as `getc()` you need to mention that in the question (and preferably in the title).  As it is it reads like you don't know how to do file access at all.  I assume this is homework?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Update:-

The famous `getc` from `<stdio.h>` is a solution:-

```
while((ch = getc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
      //...
    } 
...
int ReadFile(FILE* fp)
{
   //Do what you wish... :)
  return getc(fp); 
}
```

Declared as `int getc( FILE * _File);`

Comment: Thank you! I agree with getc but I'm required to use my own external ReadFile function. So the while loop has to stay the same.

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
while(ch != EOF)
{ 
    ch = fgetc(fp);
    //process ch
}
```

Keep in mind that `fgetc` is declared as an `int`.

Or if you wanted to build a string char by char you could read the file char by char to dynamically allocated memory like so (assuming `fp` is open for reading):

```
char *data = NULL, *tmp;
int ch, bff = 0;

while(ch != EOF)
{
    if(!(tmp = realloc(data, bff + 2)))
    {
        free(data);
        return 1;
    }
    data = tmp;
    ch = fgetc(fp);   //or your readfile function assuming it works the same as fgetc
    data[bff++] = ch;
}
data[bff] = '\0';
```

just `free(data)` when you are done with it

Comment: Calling realloc every iteration sounds expensive.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
int ReadFile(FILE* fp, int *buffer)
{
    if(fp != NULL)
    {
        *buffer = fgetc(fp);
        return *buffer;
    }
    else return NULL;
}
```