# C - how to iterate text files and check if a specific char exists

Tags: c

I am currently doing a C program, which very simply takes a file as input, and iterates over the file and checks if the character 'a' or 'A' exist inside the file. If no a's are found it terminates, otherwise it prints a message. The a's here are simply for show, I try to make a simple program that can search for any char parameter (and later extend to integers etc.)

The program is as follows:

```
int ReadFile(char* argv[]) {
FILE *fp; 
char x = 'a';
char y = 'A';
fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

if (!fp) { // checks if the file exists
    printf("File does not exist!\n");
    return 1;
}

while (!feof(fp)) { // keeps reading until file end of file (feof)
    if (*fp == x || *fp == y) {
        printf("no A's are allowed!\n");
        return 1;
    }
}
fclose(fp); // always close file after use
printf("Ok\n");
return 0;
}
```

The problem however is currently I am trying to compare a `fopen` with a `char`, with:

```
if (*fp == x || *fp == y) {
        printf("no A's are allowed!\n");
        return 1;
    }
```

which does not work for obvious reasons.

My question is how do I either cast a `fopen` to a `char`, so the file pointer returns a `char` that I can evaluate upon - or how can I solve this issue otherwise?

Comment: You are misusing `feof`. It returns whether **an earlier read** set the EOF flag on the handle.

Comment: You never read from the file!!! `fgetc`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading a file one char at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12269125/reading-a-file-one-char-at-a-time)

Comment: @ikegami Hmm can you elaborate? I've been using this technique so far for programs that reads a file and ouputs to the terminal, which similar setup, and it works fine?

Comment: You need to get a good beginners book or tutorial about C, because that's not how you read from a file.

Comment: Also read [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: @KenLar forget this tutorial (which one BTW?). There are a lot of crap tutorials out there.

Comment: @KenLar Obviously Someprogrammerdude intends to point out that *checking for `feof(file)` is usually wrong* and this is *explained in the link*...

Comment: OT: `int ReadFile(char* argv[])` is strange, it should probably be `int ReadFile(const char *filename)... fopen(filename, "r");` and call it like this: `ReadFile(argv[1])` after checking that `argc >= 2`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I'ts written inside the main function, I prob just forgot to change this when I made a seperate function :) thanks for pointing out. In regards to the toturials it was a 50-split toturial on Youtube, cant remember the name to be hornest, but it was that signature that was used to iterate files throughout several videos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "file pointer" like `fp` is *not* a pointer to the file's contents.  It is a "handle" or "descriptor" which allows you to read characters (and perform other operations) on a file which you have opened.

You need to use a function like `getc` to read characters:

```
c = getc(fp);
```

So an improved version of your program might look like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *fp; 
    int c;

    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (!fp) {
        printf("Can't open file %s: %s\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
        if (c == 'a' || c == 'A') {
            printf("no A's are allowed!\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    fclose(fp); // allways close file after use

    printf("Ok\n");

    return 0;
}
```

The big difference is that I'm not calling `getc` to read characters from `fp` and storing them in a variable `c`.  (Note also that `c` is declared `int`, not `char` as you might expect.  This is important.)

Other improvements:

1. I got rid of the call to `feof`.  See "[Why is `while ( !feof (file) )` always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)"  I replaced it with `while((c = getc(fp)) != EOF)`, which is admittedly rather obscure at first, but it's a classic C idiom which you'l need to learn soon enough.  (I understand what you thought the `feof` code did, and why you thought it worked, but trust me, it's no good.)
2. Files can fail to open for reasons other than that they don't exist.  I added a call to `strerror` to explain why the file-open might have failed.
3. I got rid of the `x` and `y` variables, which you didn't really need.
4. I renamed `ReadFile` to `main` to make it a standalone program.

Comment: That is exactly was I was looking for, thanks alot! solved my problem. Easy to understand, I read about the getc function but did not think about using it to convert the fp to what I was looking for.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, I have not yet worked with strerror, but its nice to know in advance how I can treat any potential errors when trying to open af file.